# "Lerna List" and "Lerna Changed" Returns 0 Packages

Tags: lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, npm-package

## Gist

I have a monorepo and I am using [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) and [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) to manage it. I had no issues with it until now. I need to know all the changed packages since the last release.

## Issue

So I run `lerna changed` ([docs](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/changed#readme)), but this is what it returns:

```
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.16.4
lerna info Looking for changed packages since v0.3.0
lerna info No changed packages found
```

Similarly, lerna doesn't find any packages when running `lerna list` ([docs](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/list#readme)):

```
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.16.4
lerna success found 0 packages
```

It seems like something is broken. But I can't find any issues in my setup.

## Setup

#### File tree

```
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── enums
│   ├── event-sourcing
│   ├── models
│   └── utils
└── services
    ├── consumer
    ├── frontend
    ├── gateway
    └── ideas
```

#### lerna.json

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*",
    "services/*"
  ],
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "useWorkspaces": "true"
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "cents-ideas",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*",
    "services/*"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.16.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.2"
  }
}
```

The entire repository is on [GitHub](https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas/tree/develop), if you want to take a closer look at it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The solution is very simple. As all my packages have a `"private": true` in their `package.json` files, I need to add the `--all` flag.

```
lerna changed --all
```

```
lerna list -all
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. What is considered a "release" if all of the packages are private? I am in the same boat, have all my packages marked as private. Now, for the next deployment, I need to know the changed packages. How do we go about it? How do we mark a release here?